# MOSFET power-on delay

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, delay

I have a circuit where, when first plugged in, I need to delay a few hundred milliseconds to avoid drawing power during contact bounce/not all pins connected.

I haven't done much with designing MOSFET/transistor circuits, but feel this should be a pretty basic circuit to implement.

The below is what I have come up with, but I feel is over-complicated, and takes a while to to discharge between delays. The key specs that I need are: rated to 36 V operation (24 V nominal), 500 mA peak.

Is there a simpler circuit I am overlooking, or any simple improvement I can make to reduce the reset time of the circuit?

Live version of the circuit [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAnEFPPEXGt178EKKN3jw2Ad35pwNQZjFhFUNgHluKQQPAZC-SIIiQZ2pfgtHBZ2Sh0KlGFWrNcHlvp6fiwkqXtHPR4+PTshMNFrbGizAGMY4xi48GZyGDhTWEh2LlixNCjXW2RJNgBzEDwqAuqqGjBDKjMtGmJDVUF2ww7wdVlsbEM67DxdOPMxibEekTEIuaKKNWX3Wj7lufCytkSEVasD3WSWnKyoHOys8x86mvn1LR8u6z7TNgBnet8Xt36AGYAQwANp8GGwAG4-e5UV4tWhURwImAINgA2hNCR8RqdNSNcDQJCZFBTaKvGhwXyLbAlWiEExucxzCmbKxmDFDEbJaY2OSE4mwUmDYaPUKPCK82m1cYSsmFKy47EDDbc7p9OoRY587anNgADwokE6fUIkBUpFo4EMAAUOAwAC4MAB2ABMADqfAAyAHsga62NhBAAvF0MDhMbDQegQMDQDCqAp4MDEHj+dDpcQoc4BXOyqMxtjB-ii0al5JiUPO8OR6NTeSvOrw27CPRcvnrJXiruUvwBTgltWD6xI3NTUU+GgMkfM6eT6fN2RTxnqvG2ZlY8W88WLTeKze9sw+8BhBaI4g4s6mcBsY+sfkNSAXxGXa-sY9iWniSnPwVvthAA)

[image: Circuit]

Comment: You must ask a question. What’s downstream of this circuit? If you have an MCU or similar, can’t you solve it via power on reset?

Comment: What's your question? Please edit it to include specific questions. Please note that asking for product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @winny The downstream circuit has a micro-controller, along with other analog components, however by the time the 3.3v rail comes up it will already be too late. The power to this board is provided over the common mode voltage of magnetically isolated differential pairs (think poor mans POE), I have found that when plugging in one side of a pair may make contact first, and current through the unbalanced pair has a high chance of causing a spike on the downstream side of the magnetics. Testing with a bodged in power up delay fixes this problem (confirmed by a couple hundred test insertions)

Comment: @NStorm question updated to be a little more clear.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. How will delaying the 3.3 V rail fix the problem? What about a restart?

Comment: @winny this is delaying the full input power to the board preventing the dc-dc startup, capacitor inrush and actual loads on the board. This helps ensure a fully plugged in connector and even pair loading.

Comment: A goal oriented rephrase of this question may be: *Given a 24 V power source with a "bouncy" plug in, how do I power part of the downstream loads when a (step-down fed, apparently) MCU is ready only?* A somewhat obvious answer being *make the MCU switch those on*.

Answer (score 1):

The discharge between delays can be solved with an extra diode and resistor to ground. Another diode in positive feedback can help to reduce resistor value.

[image]
A more simple circuit could be similar to this one, but not so fast when switching on, as there is no positive feedbak.

[image]

Comment: Hi Bravale, I did have a go with adding a diode in that location but it requires a series resistor otherwise the system will never switch on, it also needs to be pretty high value too, this is the same thing that limits making the 2M resistor smaller.

Comment: I see, maybe is better to discharge at the input, but additional resistor is need to have a clear way to ground. That means more components. See edit.

Comment: I did simulate that as well and it gives a fast ramp down until the upper mosfet turns off. Thanks for the idea though.